# Git status and commit not showing files anymore

Tags: git, version-control

I have created a new repositoty and the commit -a and status behaviour changed suddenly. The command git commit . is working and commits changed files but the status command is not showing anything changed at all (The files where added with the add command)

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of simplicity, I will assume you're not resetting the head or index.

git status shows you changes with respect to the last commit. Once you have committed all your changes, there are no longer changes since the last commit, thus git status reflects this correctly.  Modify anything and you will see this appear in

```
    git status
```

Previous changes will now be in

```
    git log
```

To see them similar to

```
    git diff
```

run

```
    git show
```

Comment: The point is that i have not committed files and git shows no changed. I do tghe following: git add file1, then i make a first commit. After that I change the file and git status is showing nothing. Another strange behaviour is that the files are visible in status and commit -a

Comment: Another strange behaviour is when I clone the repo from the local machine, every change is detected when changes are made in the cloned repo.